# How to set certain key-value pair to every html sent by nginx without lossing other key-value pairs?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to set the value of `mode` in every html's search string using nginx. I wrote codes like this:

```
 if ( $arg_mode !~ test ){
     rewrite ^(?:/(.*)\.html)?$ /$1.html?mode=test? redirect;
 }
```

But it will cause the loss of other key-value pairs.

For example, if I request the url

```
http://xxx.xx.xx/weather/bug.html?code=12345&mode=mess
```

I meant to get

```
http://xxx.xx.xx/weather/bug.html?code=12345&mode=test
```

but I get

```
http://xxx.xx.xx/weather/bug.html?mode=test
```

instead.

The key-value pair code=12345 is lost.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to remove the last `?`. The `?` stops `rewrite` from adding all of the existing parameters.

Comment: @RichardSmith But removing it will cause double mode value in searching string. I will get `http://xxx.xx.xx/weather/bug.html?code=12345&mode=mess&mode=test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the regex over the entire `$args` string and extract the terms in front and behind the `mode` parameter. I have used named captures so that they are still valid within the `rewrite` directive. And I have not used non-capturing groupings for clarity.

```
if ($args ~ ^(?<front>.*&)?mode=(?!test)([^&]*)(?<back>&.*)?$ ) {
    rewrite ^ $uri?${front}mode=test${back}? last;
}
```

Note: use `redirect` or `permanent` instead of `last` to achieve an external redirect.

That pretty much does what you want. It avoids a redirect loop by using a negative forward assertion `mode=test`.

The other alternative, is to use the `if` directive within the `location` block that processes the request, in which case a `break` can be used instead, which also avoids a redirect loop. Such as:

```
if ($args ~ ^(?<front>.*&)?mode=([^&]*)(?<back>&.*)?$ ) {
    rewrite ^ $uri?${front}mode=test${back}? break;
}
```

Comment: I used `last` and `break` but they won't change the url address of the browser. They just return the content of new address while reserving the showing address in the browser.

Comment: @YanYang Sorry, that was my design. I have added clarification to my answer.